# How to generate powers of 10 with list comprehension or numpy functions?

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension

I am generating **this** series of numbers using a for loop

```
[1.e-03 1.e-04 1.e-05 1.e-06 1.e-07 1.e-08 1.e-09 1.e-10 1.e-11 1.e-12]
```

This is the for loop:

```
alphas = np.zeros(10)
alphas[0] = 0.001
for i in range(1,10):    
    alphas[i] = alphas[i-1] * 0.1
```

My heart of hearts tells me this is not "pythonic", but my brain can't come up a list comprehension to build this.

I've tried `numpy.linspace`, `arange`, etc, but can't quite land where I need to.  I wrote the for loop in 60 seconds, but am trying every time I write a for loop to think about how I could do it with a list comprehension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about what you want the range on: it's powers of 10

```
[10**x for x in range(-3, -13, -1)]
```

Or

```
10.0**np.arange(-3, -13, -1)
# or
10.0**-np.arange(3, 13)
```

The numpy example uses a float 10.0 because in numpy,

> Integers to negative integer powers are not allowed

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCGvNLegUiGxWCGvgIuroCgzr0Qj2tBAS6tCIS2/SKFCITNPoSgxLz1VQ9dYR0HXEExoxmpClRoa6AHV5hXoJWIqQqjBqeL/fwA)

Answer (score 3):

There are two specific numpy function that do this.

Specify the start and finish values

```
np.geomspace(.001, 1e-12, num=10)
# array([1.e-03, 1.e-04, 1.e-05, 1.e-06, 1.e-07, 1.e-08, 
#        1.e-09, 1.e-10,1.e-11, 1.e-12])
```

Or specify the start and finish powers

```
np.logspace( -3, -12, num=10, base=10 )
# array([1.e-03, 1.e-04, 1.e-05, 1.e-06, 1.e-07, 1.e-08, 
#        1.e-09, 1.e-10, 1.e-11, 1.e-12])
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know `linspace` had siblings!

Answer (score 2):

Very similar answer to @Pranav, but personally I always find ascending ranges easier to read:

```py
>>> [10 ** -k for k in range(3, 13)]
[0.001, 0.0001, 1e-05, 1e-06, 1e-07, 1e-08, 1e-09, 1e-10, 1e-11, 1e-12]

>>> np.power(10., -np.arange(3, 13))
array([1.e-03, 1.e-04, 1.e-05, 1.e-06, 1.e-07, 1.e-08, 1.e-09, 1.e-10,
       1.e-11, 1.e-12])
```